Unnecessary warnings for Freemarker classes on native image execution
I am developing a command line app with freemarker. I want to build the app as a graalvm native image using the native-maven-plugin. When I start the app on the command line (zsh on MacOS), I get the following warning:
Aug. 01, 2024 10:25:29 PM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger warn
WARNUNG: Seems that the Java 9 support class (freemarker.core._Java9Impl) wasn't included in the build

Aug. 01, 2024 10:25:29 PM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger warn
WARNUNG: Seems that the Java 16 support class (freemarker.core._Java16Impl) wasn't included in the build

I have already tried to include the two classes _Java9Impl and _Java16Impl in the image using the native image build option --initialise-at-build-time=org.freemarker._Java9Impl. Without success.
I have also tried to simply use the two classes in my application so that they are included in the native image. To do this, I added the following code to my app, which actually makes no sense:
_Java9 j9 = _Java9Impl.INSTANCE;
_Java16 j16 = _Java16Impl.INSTANCE;
if (LocalDate.now().isBefore(LocalDate.of(1970,1,1))) {
    System.out.println(j9.toString() + j16.toString());
}

Unfortunately without success, the two warnings are still displayed. What do I have to do to make the two warnings disappear?

It's not an "unnecessary warning", as it indicates that FreeMarker won't be able to use Java 9 and 16 features (such as module and record support).
freemarker.jar is tricky, as all class-es in it are in Java 8 format, except the two classes you get the warning about, which are in Java 9 and 16 formats. FreeMarkerker detects the Java version on runtime, and loads those classes dynamically via Class.forName, if the runtime is high enough version. Apparently, when  Class.forName("freemarker.core._Java9Impl") is called there, it throws ClassNotFoundException (and same with _Java16Impl). Maybe GraalVM Native doesn't support that?
Anyway, in 2.3.34-SNAPSHOT I have switched to another technique now, "JEP 238: Multi-Release JAR Files". What that does is that there are two freemarker.core._Java9Imp classes in the jar. One is Java 8 and is at the usual place inside the jar, and the other is inside META-INF/versions/9, and is Java 9. Then I just link statically (normally) to _Java9Imp (and _Java16Imp), and the Java runtime will resolve it to the correct variant. So if that works for GraalVM Native, then _Java9.INSTANCE.isSupported() should return true (assuming Java 9+), and also _Java16.INSTANCE.isSupported() (assuming Java 16+). (The warning won't be logged anymore for sure, but it's a question if GraalVM Natiev will link to the proper variant of the ...Impl classes.)
Can you try if this Multi-Release JAR approach works? (Code is pushed on Github, and also here's the snapshot repo: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.34-SNAPSHOT/)

Thank you for your message. With version 2.3.34-SNAPSHOT the warnings have indeed disappeared

Are the Java 9 and 16 features supported is the real question though.

... but not for me :-) , I don't use any of these Java9/16 functions. The most important thing is to stop getting warnings.

For others it's important, and so it would be good to know if it works.

Thats right, but it's not my responsibility to check certain functionalities I don't need. Furthermore, I don't even khow, what kind of features are Java9 and java16 related and how to trigger those functions. As I remember, there are such thing called unit / integration testing :-)

You can just call _Java9.INSTANCE.isSupported(), and _Java16.INSTANCE.isSupported() in Java, and see if it returns true. (You help if you want of course. But to be clear, this answer and the fix was done in my free time, and FreeMarker has no paid devs at all, so it's not like some company wants to make you work to do their work for free.)

I appreciate your work, of course, sorry if that becomes not clear in my postings here. I tried both statements and both returns true. I build my app with java 22 graal vm:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22+36.1 (build 22+36-jvmci-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 22+36.1 (build 22+36-jvmci-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

They returned true when you run the native image, I suppose. So then that supports multi-release jar files. Thanks for checking!
